# How to install gurobi library on Azure Databricks cluster?

Tags: python, pip, conda, gurobi

Gurobi provides a easy way to install through Anaconda on pc. As an alternative, one can use gurobi installer and run setup.py to install. I am not sure how to install this on a Databricks cluster given there is no PyPi installer for gurobi and no jar file I can upload.

This is the interface on databricks to install library
[image]

Comment: Did you try this already: https://forums.databricks.com/questions/8203/how-can-i-use-custom-modules-and-packages-i-write.html

They are suggesting to construct a custom Python egg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an ML runtime for your cluster, conda comes pre-installed, so you can install gurobi using a normal conda CLI command.

Edit: As of Gurobi 9.1, you can now install it via PyPi / pip. More info here: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044290292-How-do-I-install-Gurobi-for-Python-

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. ML runtime was in beta at that time but still it worked